# Nginx access log. Include only pages

Tags: nginx

Now in my access log file too many records, - because images and pages in same file. Is it possible move all images to one file and only php pages to second file?
(filter images and non images files)

```
server {
    root /home/nginx/site;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /home/nginx/site/_log/site_access.log;
    error_log /home/nginx/site/_log/site_error.log;

    listen              80;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/server.conf.d/php.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `access_log` directive can be used in different scopes as stated in the documentation :

> Context:  http, server, location, if in location, limit_except

So for instance it's possible to split locations for static and dynamic content and log what you want where you want.

Another possibility **since nginx 1.7.0** is to set up conditional logging directly in the `access_log` directive using a variable that will evaluate to something different than *0* or *an empty string* when logging must happen. A configuration sample, given `$loggable` this variable, would look like the following :

```
access_log /path/to/access.log if=$loggable;
```

Comment: But why I see this error message: Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "invalid parameter if=$loggable"   I tried this code [link](https://gist.github.com/tclancy/0c47c6f61744e1d312f1)

Comment: @SPnova Nginx version ?

Comment: "nginx -V":  * nginx-extras  * nginx-full  * nginx-light  * nginx-naxsi  ; Version nginx/1.5.3

Comment: Read answers carefully. `if` flag exists since version 1.7.0, you've got 1.5.3. So you have only option to use different `location`s